# Set specific time for 'now' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using the following function to read the current time:

```
datetime('now','Format','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

My output is

```
2019-10-22T14:08:07.834
```

I have another variable, J, that has the following datetime value:

```
2017-10-12T11:02:17.22
```

How can I sent the 'now' time in MATLAB to the value of J, so that when I continuously fetch the time using the 'now' function, it will tick from what I initialized it from value J?

Comment: you just want to know how many days hours etc passed since J and now?

Comment: Exactly. so if i ran the 'now', the clock should continue from what I initialized it from J, not the actual current datetime today in the universe

Comment: I don't think you can.... isn't `now` a built-in for matlab? Have you considered using tic/toc?

Comment: i am not too sure tbh. I was hoping it can be adjusted alike the Calendar object in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract and add `datetime` objects!

```
>> someTimeAgo = datetime('2017-10-12T11:02:17.22', 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS');
>> currentTime = datetime('now','Format','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS');

>> timeDifference = currentTime - someTimeAgo % default prints hh:mm:ss

timeDifference = 
  duration
   17770:35:16

>> timeDifference = duration(timeDifference ,'Format', 'dd:hh:mm:ss.SSS')

timeDifference = 
  duration
   740:10:35:16.470
```